# We are learning about LU Decomposition .. because?

Tags: numerical-methods

I know what LU Decomposition is but I don't know why we have have to learn about it. What are we using it for? (What's the point to know about it?)

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.saylor.org/site/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/ME205-4.4-TEXT.pdf

Comment: What can you use LU decomposition for? (solving a system of equations) Why can't you just invert the matrix and multiply on the other side? (you certainly can but it takes longer). Also you can do LU decomposition in-place. Which is what Amzoti's link says.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The link of Amzoti was very useful.

Comment: $LU$ decomposition is the systematic way of doing Gauß elimination.

Answer (score 0):

The source for my answer is Richard C. Penney's *Linear Algebra: Ideas and Applications,* 4th edition.

*LU* decomposition is useful if you want to solve the matrix equation *AX = Y* for many different *Y*s with the same *A* because in that case, you need decompose *A* only once, and *AX = LUX = Y* can be solved without row reduction.

Another feature that makes *LU* decomposition numerically efficient is that as you reduce *A* to get *U*, you get *L* without any more work.